# Generated topology is standard

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Show that the topology generated by $\{$ $(a,\infty)$,$(-\infty,b)$ $:$ $a,b\in  \mathbb{R} \}$, $\tau'$, is the standard metric topology, $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt:

If $U$ is in $\tau'$ then clearly, it contains an open interval, either $(a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, b)$, both of which are open in the standard metric topology. Hence $\tau' \subseteq \tau$. If $U$ is in $\tau$. Then, for each $x\in U$, there exists $r>0$, for which, $(x-r,x+r)\subseteq  U$. But, $(x-r,x+r)=(-\infty,x+r)\cap (x-r,\infty) \subseteq U$. Since these two intervals are in the basis, they must be in the topology it generates. Hence $U\in \tau'$.

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to argue on the level of sets, rather than on the level of elements. This gives clearer/cleaner arguments.

Notice that the given subbasis is contained in $\mathcal{T}$ and it immediately follows that $\mathcal{T}' \subseteq \mathcal{T}$

Taking intersections of subbasis elements, we see that $\mathcal{T}'$ contains all intervals of the form $(a,b)$ with $a< b$. Since every $\mathcal{T}$-open set is the union of such intervals, it follows that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}'$.

Comment: Is my attempt correct though?

Comment: Check my edit: I have a hard time understanding your attempt as this collection of sets you are given is not a basis.

Comment: Your attempt is not correct. This statement is false: "If $U$ is in $\tau'$ then clearly, it contains an open interval, either $(a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, b)$...". For example, say $a < b$, then $(a,\infty) \cap (-\infty,b) = (a,b)$ is in $\tau'$, but $(a,b)$ is a **finite** interval, unlike the half-infinite intervals which generate $\tau'$.

Comment: The statement would be true if the collection given was in fact a basis, but this is not true. Maybe that's where the OP went wrong.

Comment: @Lee Mosher, the collection is a basis for the topology it generates. The topology is defined by declaring a set U is open if and only if for each x in U there exists B  from the collection such that $x\in B\subseteq U$

Comment: Or am I mistaken? @Lee Mosher

Comment: Yes you are. The statement "If $U$ is in $\tau'$ then clearly, it contains an open interval, either $(a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, b)$, both of which are open in the standard metric topology. "  is false. It is easy to see that $(0,1) \in \mathcal{T}'$ but it does not contain any such intervals.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, although @LeeMosher deserves the credit more than I do.

Comment: @Lee Mosher. The only instance which confuses me is the following.. note I understand that (0,1) is a counterexample but I don't know where my reasoning fails...The definition of the topology generated by $\mathbb{B}$ is $\{$ $U\subseteq X$ : for all x in U, there exists $x\in $ B in $\mathbb{B}$ , $B\subseteq U$ $\}$. So, if U is open in the generated topology, for each $x\in U$ there exists B $\in$ $\mathbb{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.

Comment: It is because your collection is not a basis but a subbasis. You must allow finite intersections before taking unions.

Comment: Oh......... that's makes sense. I haven't learned about subbasis yet.

Comment: Yes it is not. A basis is a subset of the topology such that you can write any open as union of basis elements: $(0,1)$ shows this is not possible.

Comment: Topology generated to a set refers to subbasis.

Comment: Actually, the topology $\tau'$ generated by a set of subsets $\mathcal S$ can be defined for any set of subsets $\mathcal S$ whatsoever: $\tau'$ is the intersection of all topologies $\tau''$ having the property that if $U \in \mathcal S$ then $U \in \tau''$ (in other words, $\mathcal S \subset \tau''$). The special case where $\mathcal S$ is a sub-basis, and the more special case where $\mathcal S$ is a basis, are particularly significant and important.

Comment: @LeeMosher This topology is exactly the topology generated by the subbasis $\mathcal{S}$.